# Reinvesting money in an ISA within the same tax year

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

In September 2022 I withdrew £25,000 from a stocks and shares ISA.

I pay in £200 on the 25th of each month to the same ISA. 11 payments since April 6th: £2200.

I have just received £60,000.

Before 5th April, is it within the rules to reinvest the £25,000 and pay in an additional £17,800?

Answer (score 8):

This depends on who the ISA is with. The key feature you need to check for is whether the ISA is "flexible"; with a flexible ISA you can withdraw money and repay it **within the same tax year** without it counting towards this year's allowance.

If it's not flexible then I think you are out of luck. Firstly, I don't think you can get back the right to repay the money even if you now transfer it to a provider that is flexible, and secondly it's highly unlikely you have time to transfer it somewhere else before the end of the tax year.

Answer (score 4):

According the the [UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts/withdrawing-your-money), you may reinvest if your ISA is deemed as a 'flexible isa':

> If your ISA is ‘flexible’, you can take out cash then put it back in during the same tax year without reducing your current year’s allowance. Your provider can tell you if your ISA is flexible.